# Select - Unselect checkbox- getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

The code doesn't run, doesn't show any error as well

Here is my fiddle

```js
function selectall(source, course) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementById(course);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview1')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input id="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input id="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
-----------------------------------------
<br><br>
checkbox set 2 
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview2')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input id="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input id="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
```

Comment: IDs of HTML elements should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `id` in a page should be unique. In addition, `document.getElementById()` returns a single element, and not an array or array like object of elements.

Use classes, and select them using [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
function selectall(source, course) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(course);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview1')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input class="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input class="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
-----------------------------------------
<br><br>
checkbox set 2 
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview2')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input class="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input class="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
```

If you can't change the HTML, you can select multiple non unique ids by using `document.querySelectorAll()`, but that depends on browser's implementation, and might not work in the future:

```js
function selectall(source, course) {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#' + course);
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview1')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input id="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input id="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
-----------------------------------------
<br><br>
checkbox set 2 
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview2')">
<br> 
checkbox 1
<input id="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fasd"><br>
<br> 
checkbox 2
<input id="trainingOverview2" type="checkbox" class="" name="fadddsd"><br>
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use classname as the class name is not unique, only the id is unique

Comment: You don't need a unique `id` because you want to select multiple checkboxes.

Comment: What I mean is I cannot assign class="trainingOverview1" to the checkboxes

Comment: What do you control in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The id must be unique to each DOM element the correct way to create a checkbox group is to give the same name for  the inputs, you can then fetch them in javascript using `document.getElementsByName('name')`

```js
function selectall(source,course) {
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(course);
     for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
     }
   }
```

```html
Select Unselect<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectall(this,'trainingOverview1')"><br>
checkbox 1<input name="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" ><br><br>
checkbox 2<input name="trainingOverview1" type="checkbox" class="" ><br>
```